# root permission during installation using apt -get in ubuntu14

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, installation, apt-get

when I am trying to install giggle using command

```
apt-get install giggle
```

i got an error message

```
sudhanshu@Jai-Hind:~/Shaan/Edu/web Spider$ apt-get install giggle
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

anyone have any idea how to overcome this problem ,
I am new to linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
  sudo apt-get install giggle
```

It will ask your user password if you are in sudoers list. If you are not, should su to root and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for help , It works

Yes we need to give admin permission

```
sudo apt-get install giggle
```

sudo as prefix work for same thanks

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer just for commenting, it would be better if you accept the correct answer and add your comments  directly to that answer.